# Encrypted Letter: The Band Murder

Tags: story

So there are nine suspects: Harry Toplin, Howard Dunkin, Lonny Larry, Boe Johnny, Randy Jopkins, Terry Howdy, Gregory Baloony, Bonodono Batooty, and Maramy Duplin. They are in a line-up for killing the most famous band of all time: "The iBand".

Good thing, the suspect left a letter, saying:

> s"In) i`ak~mp* o<tJ#h }ey< d{kn{ia<lR/l {es&ri_, } e-am-na)dn(  &my}ym{  )nd-an*ma&e - ,^ir-se{ l~Rl@ai<nk_d -ye} h#Jt%o }pm!ka$i }nI?s

It might not directly lead you to the answer, but it gives you a really BIG hint.
This is encrypted, and your job is to find who is the suspect!

Comment: One more thing: It looks hard, but it's pretty easy

Comment: Have you seen [Code Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)? Puzzles like this, with "here's a code, decode it", are generally discouraged; that meta post gives some tips that might be helpful for making your puzzle more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we just look at

> every third letter of the string, it spells `I am the killer and my name is Randy Jopkins`. (Also, this is true of the string backwards too: the same message is in there twice.)

This seems like a strange confession, but it does indicate a single person.

Comment: I feel very silly for missing this, I was trying all kinds of wild decoding methods on it. Well done :)

Comment: And that is why I said it was easy

Comment: But who is the suspect that was rot13(gelvat gb senzr Enaql Wbcxvaf)?

Answer (score 2):

> your job is to find who is the suspect

It's

> all of them!

As you wrote,

> there are nine suspects…

Comment: Cheeky of you, I love it.

Comment: @Sciborg I suspect this may actually have been the OP's intention. He or she did comment (on the question) "It looks hard, but it's pretty easy", after all. And the question itself says that the letter "gives you a really BIG hint". The capitalized "BIG" points to the Notorious BIG, for whose murder there are (still) a number of different suspects.

Comment: @msh210 Really? That seems like a pretty big stretch...

Comment: @Deusovi, what, the "BIG" business? I agree. That's why I didn't put it in my answer post. I think the reason given in my answer post stands on its own and suffices.

Comment: LOL HAHAHAHAHAHA